# How to stop events from firing in pageload?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a problem. Currently, I set the textbox value during PageLoad. However, this triggers the textbox change event.

**Markup**

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtToDate" CssClass="text" 
runat="server" Width="100px" ReadOnly="false" 
AutoPostBack="true" ></asp:TextBox>
```

**On pageload**

```
txtToDate.Text = Format(Now.Date, "MM/dd/yyyy")
```

**Textchange Event**

```
    Protected Sub txtToDate_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, 
ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtToDate.TextChanged
        Me.Grid.Visible = False
    End Sub
```

How can I prevent the change during PageLoad from triggering the texbox change event?

Comment: I am redirect the page somewhere.

Comment: Is AutoPostBack set to false?

Comment: @achinth: its stop completely.I need to stop only pageload time. Do you want the code?

Comment: Please post the code. I'm not sure I fully understand. Is it firing the textchanged event after you change the text in the Page_load method?

Comment: @Teos: yes. Check the above code.. the textchange method i disable the grid. In pageload i change the textfield for default loading. The textchange event calling automatically and disable the grid..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in your question, you don't want to hide the grid during the `PageLoad` event, but you want to hide the Grid on the `TextChange` event of the `Textbox`. You can try something like...

```
Protected Sub txtToDate_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, 
ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtToDate.TextChanged
    if(Page.IsPostBack)
        Me.Grid.Visible = False
    End Sub
```

Comment: its not working!!.. The follow is 1:"search and load the short result in grid" + 2:"i have a link in grid to redirect fullresult page" + 3:"In fullresult page i have a back link to redirect the search page" + 4:"Then i fill the search content again" here the filling time its calling the event automatically and disable the grid..

Comment: can you do    If (Not Page.IsPostBack) Then
            txtToDate.Text = Format(Now.Date, "MM/dd/yyyy")
        End If

Comment: did you in your page load event ?

Answer (score 0):

Change the setting of TextBox.AutoPostback to "False". This will prevent the text box from firing those events on changes.

Comment: Maybe you should consider rethinking your design. Page_Load is the right place to alter the text value in the code behind. If this bothers your event handler, it may is not designed properly. Otherwise, set AutoPostback to false, set the Text value and reset AutoPostback = true afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting your event declaratively, you can set it programmatically after you change the text value.
e.g

```
txtbox.Text = "something"
txtbox.TextChanged += New EventHandler(AddressOf txtbox_TextChanged)

Private Sub txtbox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'do something here
End Sub
```